# TypeScript Defining a hash table of functions

Tags: handlebars.js, typescript

I'm trying to create a definition file for Handlebars, for use with pre-compiled handlebar scripts. Handlebars will put pre-compiled scripts into a string indexed hash table of functions, but I can't figure out or find how this would be defined.

A hypothetical definition would be:

```
declare module Handlebars {
    export var templates: { (model:any) => string; }[index: string];
}
```

but that's not a valid definition. The definition should work for a call like this:

```
var myHtml = Handlebars.templates["person-template"]({FNmae: "Eric"});
```

A definition like this is *close*:

```
export var templates: { (model:any) => string; }[];
```

But that's an array with a numeric index, and it's not the same thing, and VS Intellisense just decides that the functions in the array are *any*.

Comment: I think you meant to write: `{ (model.any): string; }[]` (use a colon instead of an arrow `=>`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want to use is an object type with an index signature (see spec section 3.5.3, specifically 3.5.3.3).

```
declare module Handlebars {
    export var templates: {
        [s: string]: (model: any) => string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note to others that land here: The section is now 3.7.4, for the language spec version 1.3