# Attempting to access compiled Handlebars templates file raises implicit any error

Tags: typescript, gulp, handlebars.js

I've been trying to set up a gulpfile for my front-end dev job, and I've been running into some problems. Most are easy to fix, but I have no idea what's happening here.

The relevant things I'm using are:

- Typescript
- Handlebars
- Gulp
- Browserify (with tsify)

The setup (reduced to hopefully only the relevant parts) is as following:

**gulpfile.js:**

```
gulp.task('handlebars', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/templates/**/*.hbs')
        .pipe(handlebars())
        .pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
        .pipe(declare({
            noRedeclare: true,
            namespace: "templates",
            processName: function(filePath) {
                return declare.processNameByPath(filePath.replace('templates/', ''));
            }
        }))
        .pipe(concat('hbs.js'))
        .pipe(wrap('var Handlebars = require("handlebars");\n<%= contents %>'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/templates'))
});
```

**main.ts:**

```
/// <reference path="../typings/hbs.d.ts" />
import hbs = require("hbs.js");

var template = hbs.templates["src"]["index"];
```

**hbs.d.ts:**

```
declare module "hbs.js" {
    export var templates: {
        [index: string]: (model: any) => string;
    }
}
```

I borrowed the gulp task from the [gulp-handlebars readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-handlebars) and the `hbs.d.ts` from a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12846622/238310). So far so good. The `templates.js` file outputted by gulp looks like this:

```
var Handlebars = require("handlebars");
this["templates"] = this["templates"] || {};
this["templates"]["src"] = this["templates"]["src"] || {};
this["templates"]["src"]["index"] = Handlebars.template({"compiler":[6,">= 2.0.0-beta.1"],"main":function(depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
    return "Hello world\n";
},"useData":true});
```

I'm doing something wrong though, as I'm getting an error: *"TS7017: src/ts/main.ts(11,24): TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type."* I looked into the error but [it seems to be](https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/535628) that I have to set an explicit index type, but doesn't `[index: string]` in my code do exactly that? Or is the declaration as a whole wrong?

I've unset `noImplicitAny` so I can continue working, but I like the option and would prefer to continue with it on.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want to do here, but either you are using the interface for "templates" wrong or you have defined the template wrong. Se my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example:

```
var template = templates["src"]["index"];
```

"var template" will get an implicit any type.

Some examples:

```
var templates: {
    [index: string]: (model: any) => string;
}
```

In the following foo will have type (model: any) => string. foo in this case is a function.

```
var foo = templates["src"];
```

If you do the following foo will have type any. But what I do not get is why you are doing this, you are indexing a function like an array.

```
var foo2 = templates["src"]["index"];
```

What you should be doing given your interface on "templates" should be this?

```
var foo3 = templates["src"]("index");
```

In this case foo3 has type string, given by the method return type of the function in the "templates" interface.

If you want to use "templates" in the way you are the problem is simply that the interface is wrong:

```
var templates: {
    [src: string]: { [index: string]: any };
}

// template here will have type any (but not implicitly)
var template = templates["src"]["index"];
```

EDIT: 
From the linked example on [gulp-handlebars](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-handlebars/tree/master/examples/namespaceByDirectory#running-the-example):

```
this["MyApp"] = this["MyApp"] || {};
this["MyApp"]["templates"] = this["MyApp"]["templates"] || {};
this["MyApp"]["templates"]["App"] = Handlebars.template(/* compiled template */);
this["MyApp"]["templates"]["Other"] = this["MyApp"]["templates"]["Other"] || {};
this["MyApp"]["templates"]["Other"]["item"] = Handlebars.template(/* compiled template */);
this["MyApp"]["templates"]["App"] = this["MyApp"]["templates"]["App"] || {};
this["MyApp"]["templates"]["App"]["footer"] = Handlebars.template(/* compiled template */);
this["MyApp"]["templates"]["App"]["header"] = Handlebars.template(/* compiled template */);
```

Would result in a declare for typescript that might look something like this:

```
declare var MyApp: {
    templates : {
        App: { 
            () : string;
            footer: () => string;
            header : () => string;
        }
        Other: { item: () => string };
    }
}

var app = MyApp.templates.App();
var footer = MyApp.templates.App.footer();
var item = MyApp.templates.Other.item();
```

Comment: So if you look at my last codeblock, you'll see that the compiled Handlebars.js file outputs an arbitrarily deep array (like `templates["src"]["index"]` or it could go deeper like `templates["src"]["index"]["base"]` and so on). Any of those could levels could reference to a function, but may also be able to be indexed like an array. [See here](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-handlebars/tree/master/examples/namespaceByDirectory#running-the-example).

Comment: I added a section at the end describing what you can do to declare in typescript how the handlebars structure looks. I do not think there is a simple way to do this automatically.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I suppose I could do that... I'll leave it open for now to see if anyone else can think of some other way to get around this problem.